# Cannot dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in my Gigabyte Q2542C laptop

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

I have a Gigabyte Q2542C laptop(i5 3210m,4Gb,750Gb).

First I tried installing Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit version and then trying to install ubuntu 14.04. But in install screen it says no operating system is detected and my total hard disk is free. But windows 7 is already there. There i got stuck.

So i fully formatted the hard disk,installed windows 7,and checked again.same results.

So i did a clean install of ubuntu without having windows,hoping to install windows later.
Ubuntu was installed successfully. But when try to install Windows, it says cannot install to the partition because of its on GPT partition table.

Anybody has any idea what is going on?

Is there a solution?

I need both OS for my studies.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make different partitions for Ubuntu and windows, if you want windows as primary operating system install it on the drive(that is existing before anything is installed) and do the same if you want Ubuntu as primary operating system.Follow the steps after that

1. Make Partitions using any one installed operating system
2. Install the secondary operating system on the partitioned drive 
   please give atleast a 100GB space to each operating system if you want a smooth install

for installing Ubuntu follow these links

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

for creating ubuntu live media follow this-

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You have already Ubuntu 14.04 on a GPT disk.

I would suggest you examine first your disk from Ubuntu.
It should have following partitions:

1) EFI System partition

2) Microsoft Reserved partition

If this is the case then you can install Windows 7/64-bit without problems.
If you install from DVD everything should be OK, if you install from USB you should check that the USB is formatted with FAT32 and the file "\EFI\boot\boot64x.efi" exists on USB.

If USB was not prepared properly look for "Windows 7 UEFI USB" on the internet to see how to prepare your USB correctly for UEFI booting.

After you install Windows your default booting will be to Windows.
You can change this in firmware to set default (first) OS to Ubuntu.

I also suggest to have a look at [BootNext tool](http://www.boyans.net/bootnext/bootnext.html) which allows direct booting of Ubuntu from Windows.